# Web log data extraction using regex

Tags: regex, scala, logging

Following is a sample log and I am trying to create a separate column for every type of data:

```
unicomp6.unicomp.net - - [01/Jul/1995:00:00:14 -0400] "GET /shuttle/countdown/count.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 40310
```

host - date - URL - status - byte

I am able to fetch following:

1. host = `"""^([^(\s|,)]+)"""`
2. timestamp =  `"""\[(\d\d/\w{3}/\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s-\d{4})]"""`
3. URL = `"""^.*\w+\s+([^\s]+)\s+HTTP.*"""`

but am not able to extract HTTP status(200) and byte(40310) and I've tried many regexes.
for ex, I've tried following for status: `"""[0-9][0-9][0-9]"""` and `"""/d/d/d""` and many others.

**Edit: (Answer)** Status = `"""\d+(?=\s\d+$)"""` byte = `\s+(\d+)$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use look ahead, it works just fine to catch status 200:

```
\d+(?=\s\d+$)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YibBc.jpg)

Comment: hey this work like a charm, can u help me with byte size also?

Comment: But this will capture only status value, what about other values like `host`, time stamp`, `url` etc

Comment: I think mitochoondria already knows how to extract host, time stamp, url shown in his question.

Comment: for extract byte size, use this regex:  ```\d+$```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex with 4 named capture groups:

```
^(?<host>\S+)[^[]+\[(?<ts>\d{2}/\w{3}/\d{4}(?::\d{2}){3})[^]]*\][^"]*"[A-Z]{3,} (?<url>\S+)[^"]*"\s+(?<status>\d+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0LKM8z/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?<host>\S+)`: Group `host` that capture 1+ non-whitespace characters
- `[^[]+\[`: Match 1+ non `[` characters followed by a `[`
- `(?<ts>\d{2}/\w{3}/\d{4}(?::\d{2}){3})`: Group `ts` that matches date-time substring
- `[^]]*\]`: Match 0+ non `]` characters followed by a `]`
- `[^"]*"`: Match 0+ non `"` characters followed by a `"`
- `[A-Z]{3,}` : Match http verb e.g. `GET`, `PUT`, `POST`, `DELETE` etc
- `(?<url>\S+)`: `url` group to match 1+ non-whitespace characters
- `[^"]*"`: Match 0+ non `"` characters followed by a `"`
- `\s+`: Match 1+ whitespace characters
- `(?<status>\d+)`: `status` group to match 1+ digits

Comment: hey, I think there are more open square brackets than closed ones, can u verify once again?

Comment: please check now in answer as in demo